# What is the difference between idiom "so ... as" vs "as ... as"?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I was going through a GMAT question and stumbled across this question:

*Never before had the gardening crew harvested **so many carrots at once as** it had in the fall of 2006.*

The options contained:

```
D. as many carrots at once as it did in
E. so many carrots at once as it did in
```

I marked (E) which was wrong but I don't know what is the difference between idiom `so ... as` and `as ... as`. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 4):

*So ... as* is a [negative polarity item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item), so it is not normally used in positive statements.

Positive:

> The gardening crew harvested **as** many carrots at once as it had in the fall of 2006.

Negative:

> **Never** had the gardening crew harvested **so/as** many carrots at once as it had in the fall of 2006.

(Both are possible in a negative sentence.)

Many negative polarity items can also be used in questions (eg *Have you got **any** paper?*), but to my ear that doesn't work with *so ... as*.

**Edit:** I've just noticed that my answer disagrees with what you say the test requires: in my view, D and E are both good in that context.